# Microsoft Azure: obtaining DNS name on linux with Azure API for Python

Tags: python, linux, azure, networking

Currently I have python script that utilize MSI to gather necessary credentials to obtain public IP address but I also want to get DNS name so it will be easier to connect (being the fact that IP is dynamic)
This is my current script:

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.common.credentials import get_azure_cli_credentials
from azure.common.credentials import get_cli_profile
from azure.common.cloud import get_cli_active_cloud
import sys

# Create MSI Authentication
credentials = MSIAuthentication()

# Create a Subscription Client
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
subscription_id = subscription.subscription_id

# Create a Resource Management client
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, str(subscription_id))
resource_group_name = " "
for resource_group in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
    print(resource_group.name)
    resource_group_name = resource_group.name

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

public_ip_name = []
for public_ip_names in network_client.public_ip_addresses.list(resource_group_name):
    public_ip_name.append(public_ip_names.name)

print public_ip_name[0]

result_get = network_client.public_ip_addresses.get(resource_group_name, public_ip_name[0], )

print result_get.ip_address
```

Which class/methods should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok apparently the answer was in result I already have

For any interested it's here:

```
print result_get.dns_settings.fqdn
```